# Filtering / iterating through very large lists in python

Tags: python, data-structures

If I have a list with say 10 million objects, how do I filter the list quickly. It takes about 4-5 seconds for a complete iteration thru a list comprehension. Are there any efficient data structures or libraries for this in python? Or is python not suited for large sets of data?

Comment: Why is it a list?  You have other choices.  A mapping of some kind is probably much, much smarter than a flat list.  What is your **real** problem?

Comment: or is your filtering function slow?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Itertools](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html) is designed for efficient looping.  Particularly, you might find that `ifilter` suits your purpose.  Iterating through large data structures is always expensive, but if you only need some of the data at a time lazy evaluation can help a lot.

You can also try using generator expressions, which are usually identical to their list comprehension counterparts (though usage can be different) or a generator, which also have the benefits of lazy evaluation.

Answer (score 4):

If you have uniform types of numbers & if speed is your primary goal (and you want to use python), use a Numpy array.

Comment: How do we know his objects are numbers?

Comment: I don't.  I'll qualify my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Even using the builtin functions on a very primitive integer array takes several seconds to evaluate on my computer.

```
>>> l=[1]*10000000
>>> s=filter(lambda x:True,l)
```

I'd suggest you using a different approach such as using [Numpy](https://numpy.org/) or lazy evaluation with [generators](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#generators) and/or using iteration module [itertools](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html)

Comment: That is not an integer array, and it is hardly primitive. It's a resizable, heterogenous list with various optimized operations like `append` and `extend` that give you O(1) performance where a primitive array would not. Indeed, a `numpy` array is closer to a primitive integer array than a Python list. In Python 3 `filter` already is lazy.