# Find all substrings of a really long string - Memory error

Tags: python, python-3.x

I was solving a problem in hackerrank and it required me to create a list that can store millions of values.
And when I created a list in the normal way, but it is giving me "Memory Error"

[I have read this question and it didn't help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4800858/filtering-iterating-thru-very-large-lists-in-python)
So, please, don't mark this question as a duplicate

Here is the code:

```
def find_all_substrings(string):
    list3=[]
    length=len(string)
    list1=[]
    for i in range(length):
        for j in range(i,length):
            list1.append(string[i:j+1])

    for x in range(len(list1)):
        if (list1[x] not in list3):
            list3.append(list1[x])
    return list3

S=str(input())
list1=(find_all_substrings(S))
```

This is the error I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "solution.py", line 36, in <module>
  File "solution.py", line 7, in find_all_substrings
MemoryError
```

When the test case input is:

> NANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANAN

Comment: And how did the other question not help? Could you also explain exactly what it is you're trying to do with the code?

Comment: These types of challenges are all about figuring you smart solution. They are designed to fail on brute-force approaches. Rethink your solution. Base line is you do no have to create all of these lists.

Comment: Are you sure the hackerrank problem explicitly asked for a list of "millions of values" or are you exaggerating? For example, you might be able to make a generator function - then you won't need to store all the values in a list

Comment: @cricket_007: some of the test cases contained millions of values

Comment: Maybe share the problem page ?

Comment: Chances are you're algorithm is not what is intended.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [why-python-memory-error-with-list-append-lots-of-ram-left](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4441947/why-python-memory-error-with-list-append-lots-of-ram-left)

Comment: Are you supposed to return the substrings or just the count of them?

Comment: Can you please post a link to the actual question?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell, `list3` is completely unnecessary. You are likely running out of memory because if all elements in the first list are unique, you've doubled the required storage space to solve the problem.

Option 1) You can check if the substring is already in the list in the first loop

Option 2) if you want to prevent duplicates, don't use a list, use a `set()`, and just add to it, no need to check if something exists already. Then convert that back to a `list()` when you return.

Comment: Error is shown in the line where items are added to list1. So I guess list1 itself is actually causing the problem.  I will try using set() and will let you know the result

Comment: I think your nested loop looks fine, and you can't solve the problem better than O(N^2). It's just a matter of picking the proper data structure to keep memory usage at a minimum while you iterate and slice the really large string. Some approaches are here.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2560262/generate-all-unique-substrings-for-given-string